# Excel copying data went wrong when recording macro

Tags: excel, vba

so I recently ran into an issue when recording a macro in Excel. (I want to automate my colleagues shifts list)

[CLICK TO VIEW GIF](https://gyazo.com/1e2aec67bcef11b707e3591b6c4a8178)

So to describe the bad behavior in this GIF: I created 4 buttons that should copy cells, for Example "Add Construsoft" should copy those 3 Construsoft cells and "Add Timber" should copy 2 Timber cells in that sheet, but a there's a problem because "Add Timber" Macro remembers the same cells, so I what I need is that when "Add Construsoft" button is pressed, "Add Timber" button should count with three more cells inserted. Is there any way you can help me out guys? Thank you very much.

[CODE HERE (I RECORDED THAT MACRO)](https://prnt.sc/rml4zo)

```
'
' Add_Construsoft Macro
'

'
    Rows("17:17").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Rows("17:17").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("A14:A16").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A17").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("C18").Select
End Sub
Sub Add_Timber()
'
' Add_Timber Macro
'

'
    Rows("20:20").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("A18:A19").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A20").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("D33").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe use named ranges?

Comment: How should I manage to do that? :D Sorry for being such an idiot I just started with this.

Comment: Please help :( I don't know.

Comment: I would research named ranges: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/refer-to-named-ranges) is a good discussion that hopefully you can find something similar to in your native language.